# How to make an editable prefixed value in a React input box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

Any suggestions on how to make an editable input box with a pre-set value? For example, if this is the input box:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

the user can click on this box and start editing on top of it

```
http://localhost:3000/sendAPI
```

or change the pre-set value

```
http://localhost:8080/sendAPI
```

But overall, when the app loads, `http://localhost:3000/` is the initial value set, and when the user clicks on the input box, the value attribute will change to whatever is in the input box. Thank you!

Comment: Create a state variable 'inputText' set some initial value in that . <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value={this.state.inputText}>. Onchange , you can update the state variable to have the latest value.

Comment: Hi, I tried your method and it doesn't let me edit the input box. Any guess why?

Comment: I mentioned the method in the solution , please check that once . It is working solution,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use the variable containig the pre-set value and connect it to the input's value and onChange event.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("http://localhost:3000");

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={url} onChange={(e) => setUtl(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This worked! But whenever I try to edit the url, my cursor gets dragged to the end of the url for every character I add. I'm guessing this is because the state is updated and the default thing to do is to move cursor to the end of the url. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix the cursor?

Comment: That happens because state change causes re-rendering.
You might want to use a differen event than onChange if that is an issue, maybe onBlur...

Comment: Great, happy I could help :)

Comment: But why it's not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below solution please . Initially value will be set to "http://localhost:3000" . Once you start change , the value will be keep updating.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      inputValue: 'http://localhost:3000'
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

   handleChange(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```